# Youtube API automatically filters out "alphabet/number-added to search string"?

Tags: youtube-api

Let's say I search Youtube API for "Metric"

But I don't want search results like "econometrics" "metrics"

So I mean NO alphabet or number should be added to the left or right to the search string.

A space can be put to the left or right to the search string, like "Fun Metric course".

I was thinking about this.

But interestingly, when I search Youtube website (not API), if I search for "Metric", then only search results with "Metric" but no "econometrics" are displayed.

Another example: If I search for "microecon", then no search results with "microeconomics" are displayed.

Does Youtube website automatically filters out such words (like econometrics which have alphabets added to original search string "metric") even if I don't ask it to do so?

Similarly, does Youtube API (NOT website) automatically filters out such words (like econometrics which have alphabets added to original search string "metric") even if I don't ask it to do so??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690292/youtube-api-vs-regular-search-query-differences

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I read it, its a totally different question :)

Comment: Two slightly different questions with exactly the same answer (as given by a YouTube (google) employee, no less!). They (YouTube) don't guarantee that the results you get from the API match what you get from the search on the website. If they don't supply enough documentation on how the API search actually works (assuming you've read it), then you might use their support channels.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh No, completely completely different questions. I am NOT asking if youtube website and API give me the same outcome. Please reread it.

Comment: I read your question. I understand your question. However, the answer boils down to a) the differences between the search methods, and b) how the youtube search API actually works. It doesn't matter that the question is in a different form, the answer is the same.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh No, I am asking "Does Youtube website automatically filters out such words (like econometrics which have alphabets added to original search string "metric") even if I don't ask it to do so?

Similarly, does Youtube API (NOT website) automatically filters out such words (like econometrics which have alphabets added to original search string "metric") even if I don't ask it to do so??"

Comment: @David-SkyMesh So, I am asking "Does Youtube website do blahblah?" and "Does Youtube API do blahblah"?  If I KNEW youtube website does blahblah, then "Does Youtube API do blahblah" boils down to asking "Are youtube website and API the same?" BUT, I do NOT know youtube website does blahblah. So, I am asking about that blahblah, NOT about whether website and API are the same.

Comment: Maybe you should ask if any help documentation exists that give some tips or suggestions how to formulate a query. Exact matching is easier (faster) than partly matching. Also people can provide tags (that are hidden for other users) or youtube may generate some from the title (and description). It seems they don't tell how to get the same results using the api as compared to youtube.

Answer (score 0):

It may be different for api version 3, but the documentation only refers to "The q parameter specifies the query term to search for".
But there is some brief documentation for this q paramter in api version 2.
See:https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#qsp

Since it's very brief, here it is also:

The q parameter specifies a search query term. YouTube will search all video metadata for videos matching the term. Video metadata includes titles, keywords, descriptions, authors' usernames, and categories.
Note that any spaces, quotes or other punctuation in the parameter value must be URL-escaped.

To search for an exact phrase, enclose the phrase in quotation marks. For example, to search for videos matching the phrase "spy plane", set the q parameter to %22spy+plane%22.

Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter to boating%7Csailing. (Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped.)

Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter to boating&7Csailing+-fishing.